# Making normalized version of string in sqlite - polish character ł

Tags: objective-c, database, string, sqlite

Apple delivers example of making additional column in database with normalized version of text stored in database:
[DerivedProperty](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DerivedProperty/Introduction/Intro.html)

There is function normalizeString which contains code:

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithString:unprocessedValue];

CFStringNormalize((CFMutableStringRef)result, kCFStringNormalizationFormD);
CFStringFold((CFMutableStringRef)result, kCFCompareCaseInsensitive | kCFCompareDiacriticInsensitive | kCFCompareWidthInsensitive, NULL);
```

I've tested this method and there is example of conversion of text to normalized version:
`ąĄćłŁÓŻźŃĘęĆ` -> `aacłłozzneec`

all diacritic characters were changed properly except characters: `łŁ`

Is there any other option to make proper normalization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't speak polish, so my answer may be terribly wrong, but according to http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.2.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt the characters "ł" and "Ł" are not
combinations of an "ordinary" character with a diacritical mark.

The entry for "ą" in the Unicode Data file is

```
0105;LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH OGONEK;Ll;0;L;0061 0328;;;;N;LATIN SMALL LETTER A OGONEK;;0104;;0104
```

and the sixth field "0061 0328" shows that "ą" can be decomposed into "a" and U+0328 (COMBINING OGONEK).

But the entries for "ł" and "Ł" are

```
0141;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L SLASH;;;0142;
0142;LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;LATIN SMALL LETTER L SLASH;;0141;;0141
```

where the sixth field is empty, so these characters do not have a decomposition.

Therefore I doubt that there will be any function that normalizes "ł" into "l", and you
would have to do that using

```
[result replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"ł" withString:@"l" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [result length])];
```