# How to remove diacritics from a String in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

How to remove diacritics (or accents) from a `String` (like say change "één" to "een") in Swift? Do I have to go back to `NSString` or can it be done within Swift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can also be done applying a `StringTransform`:

```
let foo = "één"
let bar = foo.applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)!
print(bar) // een
```

---

Or implementing a custom property to `StringProtocol`

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var strippingDiacritics: String {
        applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)!
    }
}
```

---

```
let bar = foo.strippingDiacritics
print(bar) // een
```

Answer (score 200):

You can operate directly on a Swift `String` (if "Foundation" is imported):

```
let foo = "één"
let bar = foo.stringByFoldingWithOptions(.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
print(bar) // een
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let foo = "één"
let bar = foo.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
print(bar) // een
```

Comment: Excellent answer as always. Note that stringByFoldingWithOptions is a method from NSString. This takes advantage of the seamless bridging between NSString and String in Swift 2. Things are different in Swift 3.

Comment: @codddeer123: Looks like similar case as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837527/1187415: U-0141 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE does not have a decomposition into a base character and a combining mark. Or (as I understand it) the Unicode standard does not define a relationship between `Ł` and `L`.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for quick response. So in case of Ł i should remove it manually?

Comment: @codddeer123: I do not know a better solution.

Comment: This is fantastic! If I set it with "locale: .current" and then the app is used in a country where the current locale supports some type of accented character, will that make a difference? Is there a difference in making this call with "locale: nil" vs .current?

Comment: @RanLearns: I *assume* that  `locale: nil` will apply the general Unicode rules, and `locale: .current` those of the current languages. But I have not tested it.

Comment: @MartinR `Locale: nil` uses the system locale.

Comment: I tried, any to keep space in result String?

Answer (score 24):

Update to @MartinR's answer… a **Swift 3** extension to provide a string for sorting / searching, that might be useful for someone…

```
extension String {
    var forSorting: String {
        let simple = folding(options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .widthInsensitive, .caseInsensitive], locale: nil)
        let nonAlphaNumeric = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted
        return simple.components(separatedBy: nonAlphaNumeric).joined(separator: "")
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
print("Mÿ nâMe ís jÄço´B".forSorting) // "mynameisjacob"
```

Comment: You should now that sorting is very locale dependent. For example, in my language "ch" is one letter between "h" "i". For sorting thay is diacritics insensitive just use the correct string search options.

Comment: For sorting you should use `localizedStandardCompare`.

Answer (score 13):

This is my solutión

**Swift 5**

```
    extension String {

        func unaccent() -> String {

            return self.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer update for `Swift 5.0.1`

```
func toNoSmartQuotes() -> String {
    let userInput: String = self
    return userInput.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
}
```

and use it `someTextField.text.toNoSmartQuotes()`

Comment: Just be aware that the change is larger than what your method name implies.