# Is there a way to convert special characters to normal characters in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Suppose I have the String value with special accents :

```
éáüîāṁṇār̥
```

Is there a universal/dynamic way to convert/strip these types of characters down to a basic formatting like ?..

```
eauiamnar
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `stringByFoldingWithOptions` and pass `.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch`

```
let s = "éáüîāṁṇār̥"
let r = s.stringByFoldingWithOptions(.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, locale: nil)
print(r) // prints eauiamnar
```

Comment: Another reference here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521951/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-a-string-in-swift