# Replace character in a long dictionary with swift

Tags: swift, swift-dictionary, swift-string

I want to replace some characters in a dictionarys keys. There are about a hundred thousand keys in the dictionary. With the code below, this takes about an hour. Can we shorten this time by making changes in the coding?

for example:

```
dict.charactersToChange[x][1] = "á à ã ả ạ â ấ ầ ẫ ẩ ậ ă ắ ằ ẵ ẳ ặ"

dict.charactersToChange[x][0] = "a"
```

```
func charactertransformation() {
    for (key, _) in words {
        var newWord = key.lowercased(with: Locale(identifier: dict.localIdentifier))

        for x in 0..<dict.charactersToChange.count {
            dict.charactersToChange[x][1].forEach { char in
                newWord = newWord.replacingOccurrences(of: String(char), with: dict.charactersToChange[x][0])
            }
        }

        words.switchKey(fromKey: key, toKey: newWord)
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll get more engagement from answerers if you translate your code to English, so they can better understand it.

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Are you just trying to remove the accents and diacritics from a String? There's already a built-in method to do that performantly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29522097/3141234

Comment: @Alexander Isn't the code is in English?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour It was edited to be, but it was originally German: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69418623/revisions

Comment: yes i fixed the code. yes, this is what i was looking for. by checking now @Alexander