# .diacriticInsensitive working correct in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, nsstring

In swift 3 I use following code:

```
let str = "Hello Ž Đ Š Č ž đ ć č š"
let x = str.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
```

but x will be `"Hello Z Đ S C z đ c c s"`.

How can I achieve that `"Đ"` and `"đ"` will be `"D"` and `"d"`?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836975/ios-cfstringtransform-and-Đ. – As I understand it, `Đ` is a separate character and *not* the combination of `D` with a diacritical mark.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I have to use this: let y = x.replacingOccurrences(of: "Đ", with: "D")