# Swift string replace occurrences

Tags: ios, swift

I want to replace some character occurrences with english letters using Swift. Replace code:

```
let turkish = ["ı", "ğ", "ü", "ş", "ö", "ç"]
let english = ["i", "g", "u", "s", "o", "c"]

var city = "Ağri"
var result = ""

for i in 0..<turkish.count {
    var target = turkish[i]
    var destination = english[i]

    result = city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: destination, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch | NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}
```

It does not replace "ğ" with "g". What's strange is that, if I type it directly like this:

```
result = city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("ğ", withString: "g", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch | NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

it works perfectly fine.

Why doesn't it, when I first assign the value to a `String` variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to remove a variety of accents and diacritics. One way that you can do that is using [`CFStringTransform`](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/).

In Swift it would look something like this:

```
let original = "šÜįéïöç"
var mutableString = NSMutableString(string: original) as CFMutableStringRef
CFStringTransform(mutableString, nil, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, Boolean(0))

let normalized = (mutableString as NSMutableString).copy() as! NSString
// = sUieioc
```

### Edit

As was [pointed out by Martin R in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29522097/608157). You can do the same without Core Foundation:

```
let original = "šÜįéïöç"
let normalized = original.stringByFoldingWithOptions(.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
// = sUieioc
```

Comment: The same can be done directly on a Swift string, without CoreFoundation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521951/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-a-string-in-swift (which I learned from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15155624/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR Interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: thanks. It is a better solution than iterating and replacing the characters.

Comment: *Remark:* This will not replace "ı" (LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I) by "i".

Answer (score 2):

It occurs because you replace the occurrences of city but assigning the new value to result. This way only the last character is replaced in result.
Just remove the result variable and change this line:

```
result = city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: destination, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch | NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

to this:

```
city = city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: destination, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch | NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```